# download tar file via php after form submit

Tags: php, ajax, download

I have a form a user fills out, then presses "Save". The form data is sent via AJAXto a php file for processing.  The php file writes the form data to a file and tars up several files. I'd then like the tar file to be downloaded via the browser.

When the user presses "Save", the form data is written to the file. The form hangs for ~30 seconds, the tar file is written to my screen, and the form cleared.  The download code seems to be straightforward:

```
  $filename = '/var/www/html/temp.tar';
  ob_clean();
  header( 'Content-Type: archive/tar' );
  header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename( $filename ) . '"'  );
  header( 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' );
  header( 'Content-Length: ' . filesize( $filename ) );
  readfile( $filename );
```

I have tried various Content-type lines such as

```
  header( 'Content-Type: application/x-tar' );
  header( 'Content-Type: application/tar' );
  header( 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' );
```

There are no errors in my httpd/error_log or in Firefox console. The tar file exists and for testing sake is 777.

I'm at a loss as to what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try with 'application/gzip' - tar is compressed file and it's not an [official media type](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml)

Comment: I did that, and while the form submits (no hanging), the file is still displayed on my screen versus being automatically downloaded.

Comment: Update: the form does not actually submit.